# How to register single reducer using StoreModule.forFeature with ngrx 8.0.0 beta

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-store-4.0

in my feature module, im using the createReducer method to create my reducer as follow:

```
export const reducer = createReducer(
new InitState(),
on(loadData, state => {
return {
...state,
isLoading: true
};
})
);
```

but when i register the above reducer in the module class as following:

```
StoreModule.forFeature('my-module', reducer),
```

im getting the following error when compiling the project:

***ERROR myModule.module.ts(38,47): Error during template compile of 'MyModuleModule'
Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'createReducer' was called in 'reducer'
'reducer' calls 'createReducer' at myreducer.reducer.ts(14,24).***

Does anyone know what might go wrong? or how do i register single reducer, because all the examples i have seen are using combineReducers with multiple reducers, and i wonder if for just one reducer, how do we do it?

Thank you much!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap your reducer so that it is compatible with AOT compilation:

```
export function myAOTSafeReducer(
    state: State | undefined,
    action: Action
) {
    return reducer(state, action);
}
```

Then refer to this exported named function in the state.

Comment: I'm here because of saturday's stream :P
I told you to leave the old upgrade-path away and rely on the ng-update schematics, but no, you went directly into the packages and got your nightmare, oh well :P

Comment: BTW, I took my sunday to build a demo and write about the Reactive Datasource I mentioned: https://medium.com/@matheo/reactive-datasource-for-angular-1d869b0155f6 wanna have your feedback :)